# Can´t loop through click event- function error appears to loop through that click event?! The loop somehow doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

the div elements should be self explaining they all have the same class- querySelectorAll. Is there a need to put the function moveElements into another loop too and if - how to do that? The console error notification is:  Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'width') but it works when having only one event listener. ^^

```
const arrowEase = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow-start');

for (var i = 0 ; i < arrowEase.length; i++) {
    arrowEase[i].addEventListener('click', moveElements); 
}

function moveElements(){
    function moveit(timestamp, el, dist, duration) {

        var timestamp = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
        var runtime = timestamp - starttime
        var progress = runtime / duration
        var dist = 600
        progress = Math.min(progress, 1)
        el.style.width = (dist * progress).toFixed(2) + 'px'
        if (runtime < duration) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
                moveit(timestamp, el, dist, duration)
            })
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
        starttime = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
        moveit(timestamp, arrowEase, 400, 1000)
    })
};
```

asked for the html:

```
    <div id="impress">
      <div class="no-support-message">
        Your browser doesn't support impress.js. Try Chrome or Safari.
      </div>
      
      <div class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0">
        <div class="header-style header-backlayer"><h1>Assistance-Leistungen bei Arbeitslosigkeit</h1></div>
        <div class="container-step-1">
          <div class="arrow-start">
          
            <div class="arrow-1">
              <div class="diamond">
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <div class="arrow-2">
              <div class="diamond">
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <div class="arrow-3">
              <div class="diamond">
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content header-style">
              <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
              <h1>Bitte navigieren Sie mit den Pfeiltasten über die Seiten!</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

this worked - although there was a little mistake on the divs too

```
const arrowEase = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow-start');

for (var i = 0 ; i < arrowEase.length; i++) (function(i){
    arrowEase[i].addEventListener('click', onclick);

    arrowEase[i].onclick = function(){
        function moveit(timestamp, els, dist, duration) {

            var timestamp = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
            var runtime = timestamp - starttime
            var progress = runtime / duration
            var dist = 600
            progress = Math.min(progress, 1)
            els.forEach(el => {
              el.style.width = (dist * progress).toFixed(2) + 'px'
            })
            if (runtime < duration) {
                requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
                    moveit(timestamp, els, dist, duration)
                })
            }
        }
    
        requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
            starttime = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
            moveit(timestamp, arrowEase, 400, 1000)
        })
    }
    
})(i);
```

Comment: An id must be unique. If you try to find all duplicated ids you'll end up with the first one only. Assign a single class to all tags and target that.

Comment: ID has to be unique, classes can be reused as much as you want.

Comment: ok, thank you for that advice. But still el.style.width throws back an error.

Comment: Add HTML with JavaScript as a [mcve]. I am 90% sure what the problem is but I don't feel like guessing at specific things not included in this question.

Comment: sure I will upload the html

Comment: got it - it´s solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close to solutions but you pass an array of elements as 1 element.
Try to modify it like this:

```
function moveElements(event){
    function moveit(timestamp, els, dist, duration) {

        var timestamp = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
        var runtime = timestamp - starttime
        var progress = runtime / duration
        var dist = 600
        progress = Math.min(progress, 1)
        els.forEach(el => {
          el.style.width = (dist * progress).toFixed(2) + 'px'
        })
        
        if (runtime < duration) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
                moveit(timestamp, els, dist, duration)
            })
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp) {
        starttime = timestamp || new Date().getTime()
        moveit(timestamp, arrowEase, 400, 1000)
    })
};
```

Comment: so when I pass the variable into a console.log it says all 3 dvis have been read - but still there is no event on 'click'

Answer (score 0):

looks like the first time you set the SAME two parameters, as events are unique through both, it‘s overridden, assuming the last element gets the event.

2nd example you define a function inside the handler, so it gwts a new reference and can be distinguished from others.